# How can I capture Firefox's socket connection error message?

Tags: javascript, exception, socket.io

If my socket.io server is down, I don't want Firefox to display this big ugly message in the log from websocket.js:

[image]

So I have this code in place for now to try to catch the error... but still, I get the ugly Firefox message in the console when the connection fails. How can I get rid of the Firefox message and handle the exception/error myself?

```js
this.socket = io.connect( x.config.node, {
    'force new connection': true,
    transports:             [ 'websocket' ],
    secure:                 true,
    query:                  x.myUser,
} );

this.socket.on( 'connect_error', function ( err ) {
    console.log( 'Socket connect_error:', err );
    throw new Error( "Can't connect to socket server: " + err );
} );

this.socket.on( 'error', function ( err ) {
    console.log( 'Socket error:', err );
    throw new Error( "Can't connect to socket server: " + err );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you move all your socket connection code into a try-catch block.It may work

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can do that programmatically as those errors are fired from the browser and not from your code. 
You might be able to disable them from Firefox settings.